# How to change values in multiple columns at once based on value of each cell and using number index?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

In a pandas df, all cells in columns from index 4 to the end have null value or one of two possible strings, let's use "a" and "b". I want to replace each value with a number: "a" with 1, "b" with 2, and null with 0. I would prefer to change multiple columns simultaneously rather than using a loop.

I've tried using apply with lambda because it worked for an earlier project, but it doesn't work for this one, and when I use it on only one column, it changes everything to 0. I've also tried assigning the values with the other piece of code below.

```
df.iloc[:, 4:] = df.iloc[:, 4:].apply(lambda x:1 if x == 'a' else(2 if x == 'b' else 0))

df[df.iloc[:,4]=='a',4] = 1
```

The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().','occurred at index  [B]

'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replace and fillna methods

```
df.iloc[:, 4:] = df.iloc[:, 4:].replace({'a':1,'b':2}).fillna(0)
```